# Private Route53 zone and dynamic DNS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a simple question, with hopefully a simple solution.

I have a private Route53 zone, which is only available within a VPC. I want some kind of dynamic dns, so when servers are launched, they register themselves with the Route53 zone.

However, I can't come up with a clean solution. The hostname and domain are already set correctly by cloud-init and user-data, but I want a solution that accomplishes the following:

Register the hostname within the route53 zone: now, this is not too hard as the hostname is already correct in /etc/hostname. I just need to take this value and update the dns record. Not too fancy.

However, what I'm missing is how I can clean up Route53 when the server is turned off. I'm talking about the following scenario's:

- server is turned off correctly: What's the best place to put a script that only runs on shutdown?
- sudden IP change: Maybe there was a network interruption and we might have received a new IP address via DHCP. Is it possible to integrate my script with DHCP somehow?
- server lost power: maybe there was an issue at the region AZ, and we lost power. Maybe the instance is destroyed? I don't want the DNS records of those servers around in my DNS zone. Inactive servers should be removed from DNS after a few hours.

My greatest frustration is that DHCP + Dynamic DNS already solves most of those issues. However, dynamic updates via DHCP don't work with private Route53 zones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *sudden IP change* you can rule this one out.  All IP address assignments (static/manual or auto-assigned) are implemented like dhcp reservations, and the addresses can't change, accidentally or on purpose, for the life of the instance.  The VPC network layer won't even think about letting that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a feature request to clean up Route53 records tied to the instance on termination.  I'm also envisioning some kind of DNS monitor server that maybe does a ping to all servers listed in DNS, if one doesn't respond after 5 pings remove the record from Route53.